# connecting laravel and ionic fix access origin

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ionic-framework

Here the code I have used to fix access origin problem in ionic.
I have already tried `cors` package in `laravel`. need to do this in `laravel` using `middleware`.
here is my pure `php` code.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
```

please help me to do above using `laravel`.

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered from the same problem of linking ionic with laravel and solved it using the package [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors).

I allowed the **cors.php** file published by the package to allow the origins which the ionic apps will be hitting from but you can also set the config as follows to be allowed by all origins in the file

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
```